# hide jquery ui accordion formatting when printing page

Tags: jquery, css, printing

I'm trying to create an effective print.css for a running tips page. The page includes a jQuery UI Accordion to display various topics, but I'd like to not show the accordion when printing the page.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks when I print.

[image]

---

When the page is printed, I'd like for it to display as if javascript was disabled, like the following screenshot:

[image]

---

The accordion is created with a `<div id="gettingStarted_accordion">`, so hiding that in the print.css makes the whole section disappear.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add display method on your print css or media print css like this:

```
@media print {

 #gettingStarted_accordion > *{display:block !important;}

}
```

Comment: This won't work, because it hides the entire accordion content when printing. I still want to see the content; just in a format like the 2nd screenshot. I've also tried `display:block !important;`, but it didn't give me the results I was looking for

Comment: Ah ok sorry I misread the question but I do have it like this `display:block !important;` and it does work...

Comment: Yep, `display:block !important` works. I also added the `media="screen"` in the jquery-ui stylesheet to prevent the accordion look from showing up as well. Thanks for the tip about `display:block` though

Comment: ah no biggie happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

FYI I figured out a fix. I simply add `media="screen"` to the link to the stylesheet for jquery ui. Like so:

```
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css">
```

And use this in my print.css (thanks to Riskbreaker):

```
#gettingStarted_accordion > * {
    display: block !important;
}
```